# Building electron app on ubuntu fails with 'Permission denied'

Tags: ubuntu, electron, building

I tried building my electron project on my ubuntu system using the '**electron-builder**' module, but `npm run dist` always outputs this error:

```
> project@1.0.0 dist /home/user/GitRepos/project
> build

sh: 1: build: Permission denied
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 126
npm ERR! project@1.0.0 dist: `build`
npm ERR! Exit status 126
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the project@1.0.0 dist script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user/.npm/_logs/2018-12-03T10_20_50_566Z-debug.log
```

I already tried using `sudo npm run dist`, since I assumed my user might just had not the required permissions for building, but is caused the exact same error.

Here are my scripts, dependencies and linux build settings from my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "electron .",
  "pack": "build --dir",
  "dist": "build",
  "postinstall": "install-app-deps"
},
"dependencies": {
  "archiver": "^3.0.0",
  "electron-store": "^2.0.0",
  "popper.js": "^1.14.4",
  "unzipper": "^0.9.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "electron": "^3.0.10",
  "electron-builder": "^20.28.4"
},
"build": {
  "linux": {
    "target": [
      "AppImage",
      "deb"
    ]
  }
}
```

Anyone got an idea or has experienced a similar thing with electron on ubuntu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to reinstall modules:

`rm -rf node_modules && npm i`

If it has no effect, try to set executable flag of electron-builder script:

`chmod +x "$(npm bin)/electron-builder"`

or

`chmod +x "$(npm bin)/build"` for old version of electron-builder

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer.
The reinstall worked 'a bit'. It actually started building, but now it fails while doing so.

`application Linux category is set to default "Utility" reason=linux.category is not set and cannot map from macOS docs=https://electron.build/configuration/configuration#LinuxBuildOptions-category
  ⨯ EOF`

and

`Error: /home/user/GitRepos/project/node_modules/app-builder-bin/linux/x64/app-builder exited with code 1`

any other ideas? I set the executable flag of all the contents of the build folder and its contents already.

Comment: Actually, it's the next problem and I recommend you to create another question for it. But, the short answer: just add all fields of package.json required by electron-builder according to documentation.

Comment: True. Since your answer solves the specific problem from my first question above, I marked it as the answer!

Comment: edit: You were right, there was just something missing in the `package.json`.
It successfull builded now!

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules && npm i` didn't fix my problem. I still get 126 error. I'm using default electron example on ubuntu 18.4.

Comment: @Alireza Akrami It seems that you have another problem. So it's better to create another question with your logs and package.json attached.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try

```
rm -rf dist
```

As apparently there might not be sufficient permission if there were any files previously.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your bin folder and do `electronize start /watch` again. Problem solved. If you don't have permissions to delete the bin folder you need to do a `chmod 777 ./` or `chown {youruser} ./` anyway thats what worked for me.

I opened my Nix project on a windows VM and that's what hosed it for me.